# How do you set the default font for Tk widgets

Tags: user-interface, fonts, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tcl/Tk app that generates many forms and would like to be able to configure the default widget fonts from a central location without having to configure each widget with the `-font` switch.

```
#!<path>/wish
button .hello -text "Hello, World!" -command { exit }
pack .hello
puts "--- i would like to set this thing: [.hello configure -font] --- "
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding,

```
font create myDefaultFont -family Helvetica -size 20
option add *font myDefaultFont
```

to the top of your script. [(link to article on fonts)](http://www.tclscripting.com/articles/jun06/article1.html)

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with Tk's notion of named fonts, using the above makes it trivial to change the font later at runtime. All you need to do is reconfigure myDefaultFont and every widget that uses that font will instantly redraw itself using the new font. No need to manually iterate over all the widgets.

Comment: Looks like the article has vanished.  Wayback Machine says:  http://web.archive.org/web/20090302082049/http://www.tclscripting.com/articles/jun06/article1.html